# How do I set up a sign chart and graph for $\mathrm P(x) = \frac1{12}(x+2)^2(x-3)^2$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I attack this problem $\mathrm P(x) = \frac1{12}(x+2)^2(x-3)^2$?

Is $\frac1{12}$ consider a point on the chart?

If so, do I add values to it?

I know the zeros are $-2$ and $+3$ but what about the $\frac1{12}$?

Please look at my chart and tell me if I have it set up correctly.

[image]

Comment: You can ignore the 1/12, since it is a positive constant.  The intervals you want are $(-\infty,-2)$, $(-2,3)$, and $(3,\infty)$.  All the signs should be positive, since the square of a nonzero real number is positive.

Answer (score 1):

1/12 would not be a zero because it's a constant. You should be checking the signs of the function from negative infinity to positive infinity broken up by the zeros of the function that you found. Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 0):

To determine where a polynomial vanishes you must only concentrate on the terms with a nonzero degree. The constants do not matter, and so writing down $1/12=0$ is not part of the correct way this procedure is done. Here's one way:

[image]

As we would expect, the polynomial is positive everywhere and vanishes at $-2$ and $3$. If instead of $1/12$ there was a negative number, then this polynomial would be negative everywhere. Therefore: $$\mathrm P(x)>0  \, \color{grey}{\text{ if }}\,x\in(-\infty,-2)\cup(-2,3)\cup(3,+\infty)=\mathbb{R}-\{-2,3\}$$

For the graph:

$\phantom{XXX}$[image: graph of 1/12(x+2)^2(x-3)^2]

I hope this helps.
Best wishes, $\mathcal H$akim.